# How can I join a duplicate value within one object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

This is an example of the object:

```
[{index:  0,
name: "name 1",
key: "key 1",
value: "value 1"},
{index:  0,
name: "name 1",
key: "key 2",
value: "value 2"}]
```

I want to make it so the duplicated value are maintained, while the different value are added to the corresponding keys like so:

```
[{index:  0,
name: "name 1",
key: {"key 1", "key 2"}
value: {"value 1", "value 2"}}]
```

I've tried doing something like this:

```
const object : [{index:  0, name: "name 1", key: "key 1", value: "value 1"},
                {index:  0, name: "name 1", key: "key 2", value: "value 2"}]

let new = []
    for (let i = 0 ; i < object.length ; i++) {
      if (new.length === 0) {
         new.push({
          index: object[i].index,
          name: object[i].name,
          key: object[i].key,
          value: object[i].value
        })
      } else if (new.length > 0) {
        for (let a = 0 ; a < new.length ; a++) {
          if (new[a].index === object[i].index &&
              new[a].name === object[i].name &&
              new[a].key !== object[i].key) {
                new[a].key = object[i].key
                new[a].value = object[i].value
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But it ended up overwriting the previous values

Comment: do you need to group on `index` and `name` or only by `index` and take different items in an array?

Comment: I need to group on index and name

Answer (score 1):

You could take a combined key and an object for grouping.

```js
const
    data = [{ index: 0, name: "name 1", key: "key 1", value: "value 1" }, { index: 0, name: "name 1", key: "key 2", value: "value 2" }],
    keys = ['index', 'name'],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        r[key] ??= Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]]));
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (keys.includes(k)) return;
            (r[key][k] ??= []).push(v);
        });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of filter and findIndex as below:

```js
const initial = [{
        index: 0,
        name: "name 1",
        key: "key 1",
        value: "value 1"
    },
    {
        index: 0,
        name: "name 1",
        key: "key 2",
        value: "value 2"
    },
]

const result = initial.filter((record, index) => {
    const previousIndex = initial.findIndex(entry => entry.index === record.index && entry.name === record.name)
    if (previousIndex < index) {
        if (typeof initial[previousIndex].key === 'string') {
            initial[previousIndex].key = [initial[previousIndex].key, initial[index].key]
        } else {
            initial[previousIndex].key.push(initial[index].key);
        }
        if (typeof initial[previousIndex].value === 'string') {
            initial[previousIndex].value = [initial[previousIndex].value, initial[index].value]
        } else {
            initial[previousIndex].value.push(initial[index].value)
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{"index":0,"name":"name 1","key":"key 1","value":"value 1"},{"index":0,"name":"name 1","key":"key 2","value":"value 2"}]

console.log(Object.values(data.reduce((a,{index,name,key,value},o)=>
  (o=a[`${name}|${index}`]??={index,name,key:[],value:[]},
    o.key.push(key),o.value.push(value),a),{})))
```